# C++: Template Function taking rvalue reference overloads non-template function

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, function-templates

Trying to run a non-generic function but it is overloaded by a template function.

The problem is that they take **rvalue references** as arguments.

---

Here's what it kinda looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> void bar(T &b)  { cout << "bar <template> called\n" ; }
template <typename T> void foo(T &&b) { cout << "foo <template> called\n" ; }
void bar(string &b)                   { cout << "bar <string> called\n"   ; }
void foo(string &&b)                  { cout << "foo <string> called\n"   ; }

int main() {

    string msg_a = "hello a";
    string msg_b = "hello b";
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    bar(a);
    bar(msg_a);

    bar(b);
    bar(msg_b);

    cout << "\n";

    foo(a);
    foo(msg_a); // <-- I want this to call the 'void foo(string &&b)' but it doesn't

    foo(b);
    foo(msg_b); // <-- I want this to call the 'void foo(string &&b)' but it doesn't

    return (0);
}
```

```
Output:

bar <template> called
bar <string> called
bar <template> called
bar <string> called

foo <template> called
foo <template> called
foo <template> called
foo <template> called
```

When I call `foo()` with a type `string` I would like it to call the `void foo(string &&b)` function but instead it calls the `template <typename T> void foo(T &&b)` function.

Whereas as you can see with the functions that take an **lvalue reference** this is not a problem and the priority is held as normal.

---

Does anyone know a fix or work around for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo(msg_a)` cannot ever call `void foo(string &&b)` as that particular overload only accepts *rvalues* of type `string`, while `msg_a` is an *lvalue* expression. The only viable fallback is therefore `template <typename T> void foo(T &&b)`, which accepts a *forwarding reference*. Forwarding references bind to both *lvalues* and *rvalues*.

If you invoke `foo` with an *rvalue* (e.g. `foo(std::string{})`), then it will call the aforementioned overload.

Comment: In other words i need to make `foo(std::string &b)` instead of `foo(std::string &&b)` and forget trying to get rvalues, basically forcing me to strictly only get lvalues ?

Comment: @AymenTM: possibly. I am not sure what your real use case is and what you're trying to achieve. But technically that would work.

Comment: Trying to have a template function do something for all types except for `std::string`s, I want it to do something specific. Ik about specializations but isn't this like the most specific ?

Comment: @AymenTM: you could use if constexpr + a type trait instead of relying on overloading.